# Tips to extend PDOStatement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a custom database class that extends PDO. I'm looking for a practical way to manipulate query results so I can apply certain transformations to data, e.g. create `DateTime` objects from date columns.

I had the impression that extending `PDOStatement` was the way to go so I wrote a custom class:

```
class MyPDOStatement extends PDOStatement{
}
```

... and passed the appropriate parameter in my custom connect method:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO{
    public function connect($dsn, $user, $pass){
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS => array('MyPDOStatement'),
        );
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    }
}
```

I have no idea of what to do next. When I `var_dump()` a statement I can see PDO is actually using my custom `MyPDOStatement` class and I can `foreach()` the object normally but I can't find a way to alter the results. I've tried overriding the public methods, but they don't seem to execute:

```
public function fetch($fetch_style=NULL, $cursor_orientation=PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT, $cursor_offset=0){
    die(__METHOD__ . ' is actually called'); // Never happpens
}
```

... although PHP complaints if signatures do not match:

```
Strict Standards:  Declaration of MyPDOStatement::fetch() should be compatible with that of PDOStatement::fetch()
```

My questions:

1. How should I proceed with my custom statement class?
2. Is there a better way than extending PDOStatement?

**Update:** My latest findings:

- I think the troublesome bit is the `Traversable` interface. When I loop the statement with `foreach()` most overridden methods are ignored. When I call stuff in a `while()` loop, e.g.:

  ```
  while( $row = $res->fetch() ){
  }
  ```

  ... my custom `fetch()` method does run.
- If I override the methods for the `Iterator` interface as well (`current()`, `key()`, `next()`...) they never run.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `fetchObject` in your custom class, if you intend to work with `DateTime` and the like? PHP might also expect your function to have a `return` declaration like `fetch` does.

Comment: Setting `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` does not seem to call `fetchObject()`. Whatever, I need associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Have you experimented with the **PDO::FETCH_CLASS** option of the *fetchStyle* parameter for [PDOStatement::fetch method](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) ?

> PDO::FETCH_CLASS: returns a new instance of the requested class,
>   mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the
>   class. If fetch_style includes PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE (e.g.
>   PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE) then the name of the class is
>   determined from a value of the first column.

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure out what you have in mind. If I do so, the overridden `setFetchMode()` method runs but I'm not sure how to use that in my problem.

Comment: You want to modify data as it comes back from MySQL before it goes along to your other code, right?  Here you can provide a class that PHP will instantiate and stuff w/ the data from the row it's returning.  So you have `class MyResultSet` or something, then instead of an array or stdClass instance you get instances of MyResultSet back.  MyResultSet class could have some helper method to return DateTime instances out of the MySQL DATE columns by inferring which ones are DATE columns or you could have a sub-class for each table in the database for an application.  Just one approach.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of research I've decided to implement my own Iterator classes for PDO Statements https://gist.github.com/3938513

Works with foreach and while loops, and a similar performance like traditional PDOStatement::fetch

Please let me know what do you think ;)

Answer (score -2):

This might help:

```
class PDO_Ex extends PDO {

    function query($query){

        $statement = parent::query($query);
        //DO STUFF TO STATEMENT, FOR EXAMPLE
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $statement;
    }

}
```